# C++ how to create an automatic casting map?

Tags: c++, generics, types, casting

Say we have library A which contains two classes of objects C1 and C2.

For every element in C1 there is a compatible element in C2.

Say we want to create a generic function that converts from one onto the other.

```
template<typename C1, typename C2> 
C2 SpecialCast(C1 c1) {
     /* do some generic work */
}
```

This requires us to always write `SpecialCast<Type>(parameter)` However this is redundant, because all that;s needed to know the casting type is to know the parameter type. So this is adding unnecessary verbosity to the code.

And ideal solution would be to define a header table of the vallid type conversions such that one could do:

```
template<typename C1> 
C2 SpecialCast(C1 c1) {
     /*get C2 from C1 using the table*/
     /* do some generic work */
}
```

But I am currently struggling with finding a good way to define the table in the simplest possible way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a helper class to define the corresponding type. Let's say the library has classes `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`, that get casted to `B1`, `B2`, and `B3`. Ok, then:

```
template<typename T> struct type_map;

template<> struct type_map<A1> {

   typedef B1 type_t;
};

template<> struct type_map<A2> {

   typedef B2 type_t;
};

template<> struct type_map<A3> {

   typedef B3 type_t;
};
```

Now, `SpecialCast` can be defined simply as

```
template<typename T> 
typename type_map<T>::type_t SpecialCast(T t) {
     /* do some generic work */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use good old function overloading:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
T1 SpecialCast(T2)
{
    // ...
}

C1 SpecialCast(C2 c2)
{
    return SpecialCast<C1>(c2);
}

C2 SpecialCast(C1 c1)
{
    return SpecialCast<C2>(c1);
}
```

Comment: This works until you decide to also do the type conversion in another function and now you have to redo the work again. Viable solution if you know you'll only do it once though